# Jetson Orin cannot receive tf message from master

Tags: ros

I am setting a ROS network between Raspberry Pi and Jetson Orin. The master node is Raspberry Pi. And it is using ubuntu 18.04, melodic(I know melodic is EOL, but raspberry pi is mounted in a robot, so I can’t upgrade.), Jetson Orin is using Jetpack 5.1, noetic.

I connected two node in the same Wifi. I export ROS_IP, ROS_HO*STNAME, ROS*_MASTER_URI in ~/.bashrc. As a result, I can check the rostopic list which is published in Raspberry Pi, in Jetson Orin. But when I use rostopic echo command, I can’t see the data in Jetson Orin. However, in Raspberry Pi I can see the data is published successfully.

The data is tf2_msgs.

I have checked the fire wall. The fire walls in both nodes are inactivated.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This is such a common issue that I wrote a gist on it a few years ago: https://gist.github.com/chfritz/8c2adab45a94e091be77c55b0432ad2e. Check especially the troubleshooting section below the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Messaging between distros is something that's explicitly **not** supported. However, because ROS1 is all TCP/UDP based there is a chance *some* things work; but there should be no expectation that they will. This is, partly, because message definitions and communication specifics can change between distros.

Your nodes need to be running the same distro. So either upgrade to Noetic or downgrade to Melodic.

Comment: I have some reasons that I can’t upgrade or downgrade the ROS version. Is it possible to use docker?

Comment: @YJC docker wouldn't really help. The issue can be due to message definitions changing. Unfortunately, if you're not willing to make changes to the core ros installs you'll need to figure out another workaround.

Comment: I have tried another node(jetson nano) which uses ros melodic, but the result was same. Jetson nano can't receive the data from master.. I checked ping, and fire wall. In jetson nano, I can find the rostopic list, but I can't find the data. What can I do..?

Comment: @YJC that could be because you have improperly configured your `/etc/hosts` file. When the hostname/IP of every machine communicating via ROS is not there I have, in the past, had an issue like you're describing. Note: you will probably want to restart network interfaces after making that change.

Comment: I have set my ~/.bashrc like this. In Jetson, `export ROS_IP=192.168.123.144 export ROS_HOSTNAME=${ROS_IP} export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.123.161:11311` In raspberry pi, `export ROS_IP=192.168.123.161 export ROS_HOSTNAME=${ROS_IP} export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://${ROS_IP}:11311`. So I added `192.168.123.161     192.168.123.161` to Jetson's /etc/hosts, and `192.168.123.144    192.168.123.144` to raspberry pi's /etc/hosts. And rebooted both nodes. But nothing changes.. Did I understand right? Sorry for my poor English..

Comment: @YJC assuming those are the correct IPs and updated correctly in `/etc/hosts` I would guess there is an issue with the network you're running on. Changing that up(e.g. plugging ethernet directly into it) may work.

Comment: @YJC great to hear! If my answer helped consider up voting and marking it as the correct answer since that might help people in the future.